# Clicking on an example link in the topic outline list doesn't do anything

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I'm experiencing a weird bug when trying to use the example list that can be found on the right side of a topic's page on documentation, under the words "Topic Outline". ([Link to arbitrary topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams)).
I expect that, when clicking on one of the examples listed, my browser will scroll down to that example.

I'm on Firefox (53.0) and when hovering over an item in the list, I can see the link URL pop up in the bottom left corner of my browser window (which tells me that this is a link), I can right click it and open the link in a new tab, which does work (it scrolls down to the linked example in the new tab), but (left) clicking it does nothing (observable, at least).

Could this be caused by a setting in my browser?

---

When inspecting the element I get this for instance:

```
<a class="topic-outline-example-link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams/909/creating-a-frequency-map#t=201704251132200972376" data-example-id="909">Creating a Frequency Map</a>
```

Looks normal to me (though web is not my forté).

---

I tested on Google Chrome (58.0.3029.81), and it works as expected there.

I've also tried disabling all browser extensions, but that had no effect.

Comment: No repro in Safari. It's supposed to scroll the page down to an anchor target.

Comment: @CodyGray Exactly, I've seen that behaviour on other sites too, for instance javadoc, and the html element looks the same there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIL something new about [how scrollTop works in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox), so thanks for the report. :)

The fix will go live with the next production build.

Comment: Why not just use id's and hashes?